# OpenCV program crashes linux when exiting (using cvtColor)

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I've made a working application using OpenCV that crashes linux mint, after the program is finished (return 0;).

I've narrowed the code down to the snippet below. When the function cvtColor is used, the program crashes. While the code is running, nothing weird is going on and cvtColor is doing it's job.

I'm not a c/c++ programmer, I don't even know where to look further to what causes this or how to find something to help me google for a solution.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

The version of OpenCV: 3.0
Running on: 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat frame1;
    Mat grayImage1;

    frame1 = imread("lena.jpg");

    cvtColor(frame1, grayImage1, COLOR_RGB2BGR);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you use the right libraries (e.g. debug vs release)?

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"? Is there an error message?

Comment: Linux freezes for about 2 minutes, then it seems the x server is restarted. I don't have any error messages, maybe because i can't see them before it freezes. The screen shows some weird patterns when it 'crashes' and recovers itself by restarting x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV 3.0 still seems to be in alpha phase so I would recommend you to try the same with a stable release and check if the same problem exists.

Comment: That was it. I compiled the master from git, not knowing it was an alpha release. I checked out version 2.4.10.1, compiled and installed it and it works. Some refactoring has to be done now, but I'm happy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is causing the crash, but a potential problem is the conversion from RGB to BGR.

You probably wanted to execute `COLOR_BGR2RGB` instead, since the data is originally stored as **BGR**.

Comment: Old McDonald had a farm, ee i ee i o.